# Search elements of matrix in another cell in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have a column matrix and a cell array which has two columns.The first column has 1x2 doubles and the second column has 1x1 doubles.

For example

```
columnMatrix = [1;5]; 
cellArray = {[1,8],[10];[8,1],[20];[4,6],[80];[3,5],[40];[14,16],[85];[5,10],[36]};
```

I would like to search each element of `columnMatrix` in `cellArray(:,1)` and then return its corresponding value in `cellArray(:,2)`

For example the output has to be like this

```
newCell = {[1],[10,20];[5],[40,36]};
```

I tried using the `ismember` function in this way

```
[~,idx] = ismember(cell2mat(cellArray(:,1)),columnMatrix (: , 1));
```

This returns all the indices which have the searched element but they are in two seperate columns and I can not perform any other logical operation to get the corresponding second column entry.

Is there some way this operation can be achieved? Could some one please help?

Thanks

Comment: What indices does it show and how they are arranged?

Comment: `idx = [1,0;0,1;0,0;0,2;0,0;2,0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, convert first column of `cellArray` to a matrix so it would be easier to search values in. Then iterate over `columnMatrix` values (e.g. using `arrayfun`, but you could also use for loop), find rows that match (`any` across columns) and select corresponding values from the second column of `cellArray`, converting to numeric array (`[cellArray{...,2}]`). Finally, append the `columnMatrix` as the first column of the resulting cell array:

```
columnMatrix = [1;5]; cellArray = {[1,8],[10];[8,1],[20];[4,6],[80];[3,5],[40];[14,16],[85];[5,10],[36]};

mat = cell2mat(cellArray(:,1));
values = arrayfun(@(x) [cellArray{any(mat==x,2),2}], columnMatrix, 'uni', false);
result = [num2cell(columnMatrix), values];
```

Comment: Thanks for this arrayfun operation. I used the for loop but wanted to know if it can be done in another way!

Comment: If u dont mind I have a follow up question to your answer. What if the first column of `cellArray` does not have equal size doubles but has `1xn` doubles where `n>=2`? In this case the `cell2mat` returns a catenation error! Any suggestions please? Thanks!

Comment: You still need to get the logical indices. So instead of doing `any(mat==x,2)`, you can e.g. do `cellfun(@(arr) any(arr==x), cellArray(:,1))`. Note that we no longer need `mat` varialbe.